# adding a #id into data-title in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```js
<script> 
  

var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth() ;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
 //alert(year);
// Set the date we're counting down to

var countDownDate = new Date(year, month, day,12).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + " : "
    + minutes + " : " + seconds;

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000); 
 </script>
```

```css
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

@media (min-width: 992px)
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
.d-md-inline-block {
    display: inline-block!important;
}

.ya {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: nucleo;
    speak: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}


.ya-content::before {
    content: "\E015";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" >
                                <span class="d-none d-md-inline-block">global Time : <td><i class="ya ya-content" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-title="demo"></i></td></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
```

as you can see all what i want to do is put id=demo into data-title at the html code
but how i can put it at html ?
i tried making it data-title-id="demo" but did not work at all
who can help me with this problem ?
thx ........................................
...........................
..............
.......

Comment: Why not just `id="demo"`?

Comment: because i want to make it show once i get the mouse over the icon . like this one http://prntscr.com/mvfhlf

Comment: once i get the mouse to this icon you saw at the image , it show what inside data-title

Comment: trying to show a time once i get the mouse at this icon and i am using a id for the timer .